# Create variables in foreach loop

Tags: php

I want to create a variable name in a foreach loop. Do you have suggestions for me?

The $_POST['quantity'] contains 10 rows. So I want to define 10 variables for these 10 rows. I have tried something like this:

```
foreach($_POST['quantity'] as $i => $item)
{   
    $a[$i] = $_POST['quantity'][$i];
}
```

But I get a PHP error when I try to do that.

I just want to create the variables $a1, $a2, $a3, $a4, $a5, $a6, $a7, $a8, $a9 and $a10 automatically. Does someone knows how I can fix that?

Comment: `${'a' . $i} =` but variable variables are considered a bad practice. Just use an actual array.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. When I try to echo $a1 I don't see any result

Comment: Can I ask why you want to create 10 variables instead of using an array? Your example should actually do that as long as `$_POST['quantity']` is an array. What error do you get? Btw, if it's an indexed array with 10 items, then `$i` will start at `0` and end on `9`, not `1` to `10`. You can also replace `$_POST['quantity'][$i]` with just `$item`. Have you checked that `$_POST['quantity']` actually contains what you expect?

Comment: You are right, It starts with 0 instead of 1. But it doesnt matter, When I try to echo $a1 or $a0 it is still empty. quantity contains what I expect. The code also works when I manually create the variables= `$a1 = $_POST['quantity'][$i];` but `${'a' . $i} =` or `$a[$i] =` shows empty

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump($_POST['quantity'])` and then a `var_dump($a)` after the foreach (when using the code in your example where you add them to an array) and add the outputs to the question? We're kind of working blind here.

Comment: **When I try to echo $a1 I don't see any result** Do you know the difference between $a1 and $a[1] ?

Answer (score 1):

ShiaNai7 was correct. Using `${'a' . $i} =` solved my problem.